# How do I group Windows Form radio buttons and textboxes?

Tags: c#, textbox, radio-button, grouping

I have 10 textbox controls and 10 radioButton controls, and I have a code similar that, but can I make a group for the textboxes and radioButtons?

The code :

```
if (chbx_Ext_tit1.Checked == true)
{
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Nom_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
    StreamWriter fichier1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);

    fichier1.Write(txt_ext_tit_nom1.Text);
    fichier1.Close();

    //Numéro

    FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Num_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
    StreamWriter fichier2 = new StreamWriter(fs2);

    fichier2.Write(txt_ext_tit_num1.Text);
    fichier2.Close();
}

//exporter joueur 2 Titulaire
if (chbx_Ext_tit2.Checked == true)
{
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Nom_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
    StreamWriter fichier1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);

    fichier1.Write(txt_ext_tit_nom2.Text);
    fichier1.Close();

    //Numéro

    FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Num_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
    StreamWriter fichier2 = new StreamWriter(fs2);

    fichier2.Write(txt_ext_tit_num2.Text);
    fichier2.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method with 3 (or more) parameters, and just pass the controls.

```
public void Foo()
{
    DoWork(chbx_Ext_tit1, txt_ext_tit_nom1, txt_ext_tit_num1);
    DoWork(chbx_Ext_tit2, txt_ext_tit_nom2, txt_ext_tit_num2);
}

public void DoWork(CheckBox checkbox, TextBox textbox1, TextBox textbox2)
{
    if (checkbox.Checked == true)
    {
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Nom_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter fichier1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);

        fichier1.Write(textbox1.Text);
        fichier1.Close();

        //Numéro

        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Num_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter fichier2 = new StreamWriter(fs2);

        fichier2.Write(textbox2.Text);
        fichier2.Close();
    }
}
```

Or better, just pass the values you need:

```
public void Foo()
{
    DoWork(chbx_Ext_tit1.Checked, txt_ext_tit_nom1.Text, txt_ext_tit_num1.Text);
    DoWork(chbx_Ext_tit2.Checked, txt_ext_tit_nom2.Text, txt_ext_tit_num2.Text);
}

public void DoWork(bool isChecked, string text1, string text2)
{
    if (isChecked)
    {
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Nom_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter fichier1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);

        fichier1.Write(text1);
        fichier1.Close();

        //Numéro

        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(@"c:\LigueStats\data\TXT\Num_joueur.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter fichier2 = new StreamWriter(fs2);

        fichier2.Write(text2);
        fichier2.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot  Kemal, thats what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "GroupBox" control and place all your controls in there. Alternatively you can create your custom control to group your controls.

Comment: I place it into panels, can you help me with code ?

Comment: Yes I can, First, what have you done so far?  Is it a winForm application? what version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

agree with Jegan. but it is not necessary to use only GroupBox for grouping.
main concept is that to group couple of controls you can use any container Control.